# Гибкие изображения. Почему картинка не подстраивается под размер блока?

Tags: html, css

Товарищи, изучаю книгу Дэвида Макфарланда "Большая книга CSS" и столкнулся с проблемой гибких изображений. Задача элементарная: сделать изображения гибкими, чтобы они подстраивались под ширину контейнера, в котором находятся.
Согласно книге, нужно добавить код:

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

но изображение игнорирует размер блока, в котором находится

```css
.photo {
  width: 500px;
}

.photo img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1548&q=80" alt="nature">
</div>
```

[image: Исходное изображение]

Т.о. картинка не реагирует на размер блока (500px), в котором находится. Почему так происходит? Пробовал добавить к картинке max-height: 100%, результата не дало.

Comment: Я поправил Ваш код в сниппет без изменения контекста, и хорошо видно, что всё работает как Вы и задумали. В чём проблема заключается?

Comment: Спасибо, здесь и правда всё работает, как задумано. Я использую VScode, запускаю на нем Live Server и изображение не подстраивается под размеры блока. Получается, проблема в программе...

Comment: Проблема может быть только в движке браузера. Но вряд ли VSCode тут причастен к этому... В данном случае Вашу проблему можно воспроизвести только в том случае, если Ваше изображение меньше 500px, а Вы хотите строго 500.

Comment: Изображение 1920х1080. Попробовал открыть файл через Яндекс.Браузер, Edge, картинка не подстраивается

Comment: Не может такого быть. Только если Вы CSS как-то криво вписали и он не применился (смотрите в devtools), или несоответствие именования класса в тэге и в самом CSS

Comment: [Скриншот](https://ibb.co/2qYfhr0)

Comment: @ghost3ds, я не вижу подключения CSS, вот и проблема.

Comment: Вот так дочитал до 508 страницы книгу про CSS, а про элементарные действия забыл :( Большое всем спасибо!